# Как правильно пишется слово "летческая* или" летчиская"?

Tags: орфография

В нашей местности есть небольшая река, одно из мест для купания называется в народе "Летческая". Назвали это место давно, т. к. туда ездили купаться курсанты летного училища.
Сейчас возник вопрос: как же правильно пишется "Лётческая" или "Лётчиская".
Разъясните, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

[Лётчицкая](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ogegova/98242) - прилагательное от лётчик, разговорная форма.

Авиатор - авиатор**ск**ий, пилот - пилот**ск**ий, однако - лётчик, грузчик, паромщик  не *-кск-*, а **-цк-** - лётчи**цк**ий, грузчи**цк**ий, паромщи**цк**ий.

Как же я забыл... [мужи**цк**ий дождь](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tLoHI_YyS7k)! Исполняет, кстати, [Пушной](https://1zolenta.com/name/1894396363.405462616-a-pushnoy-muzhickiy-dozhd).